# nvidia-418 now depending on kernel 5.0.0 on 18.04LTS

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

I have been using nvidia-driver-418 from graphics-drivers PPA on Ubuntu 18.04 happily for half a year now. However since last week it is suddenly depending on nvidia-430 and Linux kernel 5.0.0. I do not want to use kernel 5.0.0 as it will cause other problems (amongst other, dependency issues with software that I run). Is it possible to keep using Nvidia 418 without kernel upgrade to 5.0.0?

Comment: Maybe you don't even need `418`. I use `384` on Ubuntu 16.04 and 19.04 with kernel versions 4.14.134 & 5.0-23

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that. Unfortunately 3XX seems to work way worse with my half year old laptop... (ie causing unexpected hangs)

Comment: Update: `415` seems to work fine without additional kernel dependencies. Time will tell if there are stability issues.

Comment: Update: after a day it seems that 415 suffers from a bug that gives unexpected annoying black screens. So I really need a way to continue using 418.

Comment: Update: after almost a week my system seems to work stable with `410`! so that solves the problem for me now.